# How to send JSON Response as is

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have API developed using .net 6.0, I am calling another Azure Function where I get following JSON

```json
{
    "serial_number": "0000",
     "Name": "abc"
}
```

now, I want to send response back to my API caller as it

```json
{
    "serial_number": "0000",
     "Name": "abc"
}
```

BUT it send responses as

```json
{
  "message": "{\"serial_number\": \"0000\, \"Name\": \"abc"}
}
```

following is the my complete code

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> mydevice()
{
    var url = _appSettings.mydevice;
   
    try
    {
        var response = await _Service.mydevice(url);
        string message = "Bad request";
        if (response != null)
        {
            message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return Ok(new { message });
        }
        return BadRequest(new { message });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

> return Ok(new { message });

With this you are passing to the Ok method a new object that has 1 property "message" and your message as the value of that property. That is because if you don't specificy the name of the property when creating a new anonymous object, it automatically takes your variable name as the name of the property. That's why in the response you get the key "message".

Since you don't want the "message" key to appear in the response, you can't create a new object like you are doing. Instead, try doing it like this:

```
return Ok(message);
```

The same applies for the BadRequest.

Comment: Excellent Aless!!

Comment: @user22846197 Glad it helped. If my answer was the solution to your problem, consider marking the answer as the accepted one =)